# C++ something gone wrong when reading the file

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to write and read serialized data to file, but it always breaks when reading specific "PNG" struct, with stored `"bed_feet_top.png"` from minecraft 1.8.9 textures folder in it, and I can't find a way to get the error. Already tried `errno` and `try and catch`, but it always says sucess. It seems that it breaks after and not when reading the buggy "PNG" struct, because the read data is uncorrupted and I can recreate the stored image. I'm using `"stb_image"` library to read the image data and `"zpp_bits"` library for serializing the data.

the code i would use:

```
PNG srcImage; //The "PNG" struct it will break at
unsigned char* buffer = stbi_load("bed_feet_top.png", &image.imageWidth, &image.imageHeight, &image.colorChannels, STBI_rgb_alpha);

if (!buffer)
{
    std::cout << "Failed to read image: " + path << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

image.pixels = (char*)buffer;

DataBuffer srcBuffer;
srcBuffer.serialize("somePath", "someName", srcImage); 
DataManager::writeToFile("someFile.dat", srcBuffer);

DataBuffer dstBuffer;
DataManager::readFromFile("someFile.dat", &dstbuffer);
PNG dstImage = dstBuffer.deserialize<PNG>("somePath", "someName"); //The buggy "PNG" struct data is uncorrupted
```

the "PNG" struct:

```
struct PNG
{
    int imageWidth, imageHeight, colorChannels;
    std::string pixels;
};
```

the struct I'm storing all serialized data in:

```
struct DataBuffer
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::byte>> data; //All the serialized data is stored in this map

    template<typename T>
    void serialize(std::string path, std::string name, T obj)
    {
        path.append("/");
        path.append(name);
        serialize(path, obj);
    }

    template<typename T>
    void serialize(std::string fullPath, T obj)
    {
        if (data.contains(fullPath))
        {
            std::cout << "Data buffer already contains value with te same path!" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            zpp::bits::out out(data[fullPath]);
            out(obj).or_throw();
        }
        catch (const std::exception& error)
        {
            std::cerr << "Serialization failed with error: " << error.what() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (...) {
            std::cerr << "Serialization failed with unknown error!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    template<typename T>
    T deserialize(std::string path, std::string name)
    {
        path.append("/");
        path.append(name);
        return deserialize<T>(path);
    }

    template<typename T>
    T deserialize(std::string fullPath)
    {
        T obj;
        if (!data.contains(fullPath))
        {
            std::cout << "Data buffer doesn't contain value with the given path!" << std::endl;
            return obj;
        }

        try
        {
            zpp::bits::in in(data[fullPath]);
            in(obj).or_throw();
        }
        catch (const std::exception& error)
        {
            std::cerr << "Deserialization failed with error: " << error.what() << std::endl;
        }
        catch (...) {
            std::cerr << "Deserialization failed with unknown error!" << std::endl;
        }

        return obj;
    }
};
```

The write to file function:

```
void DataManager::writeToFile(std::string fileName, DataBuffer dataBuffer)
{
    std::ofstream ofs(fileName, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    if (!ofs.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open output file stream!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    size_t dataCount = dataBuffer.data.size();
    ofs.write((char*)&dataCount, 8);

    for (auto const& [key, val] : dataBuffer.data)
    {
        size_t keySize = key.size();
        ofs.write((char*)&keySize, sizeof(keySize));
        ofs.write(&key[0], keySize);

        size_t entryCount = val.size();
        ofs.write((char*)&entryCount, 8);
        ofs.write((char*)val.data(), entryCount);

        if (!ofs.good()) //ofs.good() never returned false to me
        {
            std::cerr << "Something went wrong when writing " << key << " to the file!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    ofs.close();
}
```

the read from file function:

```
void DataManager::readFromFile(std::string fileName, DataBuffer* dataBuffer)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(fileName, std::ios::in, std::ios::binary);

    if (!ifs)
    {
        std::cerr << "File doesnt exist!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    if (!ifs.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open input file stream!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    size_t dataCount;
    ifs.read((char*)&dataCount, 8);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataCount; i++)
    {
        size_t keySize;
        ifs.read((char*)&keySize, sizeof(keySize));
        std::string key;
        key.resize(keySize);
        ifs.read(&key[0], keySize);

        size_t entryCount;
        ifs.read((char*)&entryCount, 8);
        dataBuffer->data[key].resize(entryCount);
        ifs.read((char*)dataBuffer->data[key].data(), entryCount);

        if (!ifs.good()) //ifs.good() returns false after it reads the buggy "PNG" struct data
        {
            std::cerr << "Something went wrong when reading " << key << " from the file!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    ifs.close();
}
```

**EDIT**

I added minimal reproducible example as "Igor Tandetnik" requested.

the minimal reproducible example:

```
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#include <stb_image.h>
#include "stb_image_write.h"
#include <zpp_bits.h>

struct PNG
{
    int imageWidth, imageHeight, colorChannels;
    std::string pixels;
};

int main()
{
    std::string fileName = "someFile.dat"; //The file we will store the image data in
    std::string srcImageName = "bed_feet_top.png"; //Texture from Minecraft 1.8.9 textures folder
    std::string dstImageName = "someImage.png"; //The name of image we will create from the read data

    //Reading the image data
    PNG srcImage;
    unsigned char* buffer = stbi_load(srcImageName.c_str(), &srcImage.imageWidth, &srcImage.imageHeight, &srcImage.colorChannels, STBI_rgb_alpha);

    if (!buffer)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to read image " + srcImageName << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    int dataSize = srcImage.imageWidth * srcImage.imageHeight * srcImage.colorChannels;
    srcImage.pixels.assign((char*)buffer, dataSize);

    //Serializing the image data
    std::vector<std::byte> srcData;
    try
    {
        zpp::bits::out out(srcData);
        out(srcImage).or_throw();
    }
    catch (const std::exception& error)
    {
        std::cerr << "Serialization failed with error: " << error.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Serialization failed with unknown error!" << std::endl;
    }

    //Writing the image data to file
    std::ofstream ofs(fileName, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

    if (!ofs.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open output file stream!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    size_t srcEntryCount = srcData.size();
    ofs.write((char*)&srcEntryCount, 8);
    ofs.write((char*)srcData.data(), srcEntryCount);

    if (!ofs.good())
    {
        std::cerr << "Something went wrong when writing" << srcImageName << " to the file!" << std::endl;
        ofs.close();
        return 1;
    }

    ofs.close();

    //Reading the image data from file
    std::ifstream ifs(fileName, std::ios::in, std::ios::binary);

    if (!ifs)
    {
        std::cout << "File doesnt exist!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (!ifs.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open input file stream!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::vector<std::byte> dstData;

    size_t dstEntryCount;
    ifs.read((char*)&dstEntryCount, 8);
    dstData.resize(dstEntryCount);
    ifs.read((char*)dstData.data(), dstEntryCount);

    if (!ifs.good())
    {
        std::cerr << "Something went wrong when reading " << srcImageName << " from the file!" << std::endl;
        ifs.close();
        return 1; //If you comment this line you will see it will recreate the image from the read data just fine
    }

    ifs.close();

    //Deserializing the read image data
    PNG dstImage;

    try
    {
        zpp::bits::in in(dstData);
        in(dstImage).or_throw();
    } catch (const std::exception& error)
    {
        std::cerr << "Deserialization failed with error: " << error.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Deserialization failed with unknown error!" << std::endl;
    }

    //Recreating the image from the read image data
    stbi_write_png(dstImageName.c_str(), dstImage.imageWidth, dstImage.imageHeight, dstImage.colorChannels, dstImage.pixels.c_str(), dstImage.imageWidth * sizeof(int));
}
```

I'm caling the objects src and dst, because I don't know how to call them shortly before and after serialization. :D

Comment: `image.pixels = (char*)buffer;` assumes that `buffer` is a nul-terminated C string. But in fact it's binary data - it's likely not nul-terminated, and it may well contain zero bytes. So the assignment would either truncate the data, or read past the end. My guess is, you are meant to do something like `auto data_size = image.imageWidth*image.imageHeight*image.colorChannels; image.pixels.assign(buffer, data_size);`

Comment: Thanks, it aligned the sizes of images, but still breaks at the same "PNG" struct data.

Comment: What is `image`, and how, if at all, is it related to `srcImage`? Anyway, you seem to be saying that, after `dstBuffer.deserialize` call, `dstImage` contains the exact same data as `srcImage`; or at least, that's how I read "uncorrupted". This means the code shown is working as intended. What part is not working, then? What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: My goal was to write serialized data to binary file and then read it back without any losses. It works fine with other images and data i tested it on, but when reading the buggy "PNG" struct data it breaks and starts to return the same data over and over agin for every upcoming entry. I created different post asking why it is returning the same data over and over agin and someone replied that it might be because the ifstream buffer got stuck and returns the data stored in it, but not reading further. Now I'm asking what could be the reason for the ifstream buffer to break and how to fix it.

Comment: Every `readFromFile` call constructs a new `std::ifstream` instance. Whatever happened to some other instance shouldn't affect this new one. Whatever problem you are seeing is unlikely to be caused by anything reasonably described as "ifstream buffer got stuck". For further assistance, show a [mcve], in particular the part that reads more than one entity.